# Cómo ajustar dos gráficos en un sólo eje?

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

No sé si es correcta la formulación de la pregunta pero cuando vean la imagen sabrán a qué me refiero.

Como podrán ver tengo dos gráficas, una sobre otra, uno de cajas y la otra de línea. Sin embargo, la de línea se desplaza un eje a la derecha. ¿Cómo corrijo este asunto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Por favor agrega tu código y los `dataframes` para poder analizar el problema.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Me parce que es un tema de los indices, pues, estas generando el grafico de linea a la vez que los estas generado: `MW_monthly.median().plot(linewidth=3, marker='0', ax=axl)`.

Sugiero revisar que tanto los indices de `aep_df` como los de `MW_monthly.median()` empaten. De lo que alcanzo a ver, el primero parece tiene indices del 0 al 11 mientras que el segundo del 1 al 12.